# Error when using the username-password oauth flow

Tags: rest-api, api, oauth, passwords

I'm fresh using the SF API and want to get the token by the oauth API to do some test.
After I completed creating the connected APP followed the sf spec with the setting like below:
[image]

then I got the client key/secret to make a request by Postman but always get the same error

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "authentication failure"
}
```

the curl command like below:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Cookie: BrowserId=kkYw1JsmEe6JE5H273Hk2A; CookieConsentPolicy=0:0; LSKey-c$CookieConsentPolicy=0:0' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=xxx' \
--data-urlencode 'password=xxx' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=xxx' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=xxx'
```

, no matter using the password directly or appending the security token still the same
[image]

pls help take a look is there any configuration is wrong or sth I missed

Comment: Check this It may help. - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5
- https://stories.salesforcecodex.com/2023/07/salesforce/generate-salesforce-authentication-token-using-postman/

Comment: Username/password flow is blocked by default because it's insecure - for calling the APIs from Postman, switch to [client credentials](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_client_credentials_flow.htm&language=en_US&type=5)

Comment: @identigral and Tushar
thanks much guys, followed the above wikis it worked now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you should check -

- First, are you adding the security token after the password?
- Second, check the following settings in your org. **Allow OAuth Username-Password Flows under - Allow OAuth Username-Password Flows**
  [image]

Comment: thanks very much, the root cause is this setting not enabled